# Convert List<images> into a video file?

Tags: java, image, video

I having list of `Image` instances and want to convert this into a video file it is possible.

```
 List<Images> images..
```

How can I convert List into a video file?

Comment: See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878768/converting-a-series-of-images-to-a-video-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

You can use xuggler - http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/
Xuggler is a free open-source library for Java developers for video manipulation, it uses the very powerful FFmpeg media handling libraries under the hood, essentially playing the role of a java wrapper around them.

nice tutorial:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/introduction-xuggler-video-manipulation.html

Answer (score 1):

You need a library for creating this. There are some post here about that:

[Looking for a java package to create video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175210/looking-for-a-java-package-to-create-video)

[Video Creation from a set of images with xuggler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175543/video-creation-from-a-set-of-images-with-xuggler)

or a tutorial there:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/xuggler-tutorial-frames-capture-video.html